# How to re-name routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I have nested routes on my site for Sections and Pages.

```
  resources :sections do
    resources :pages
  end
```

This is a sample URL:

```
sitename.com/sections/5/pages/22
```

I don't like the name 'sections', and would prefer 'chapters'.

```
sitename.com/chapters/5/pages/22
```

I assume re-naming the model would be to complicated, so how can I just re-name the route easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your desired URL segment name as the value to the `path` argument:

```
resources :sections, :path => :chapters do
  resources :pages
end
```

This results the the following routes:

```
           section_pages GET    /chapters/:section_id/pages(.:format)          pages#index
                          POST   /chapters/:section_id/pages(.:format)          pages#create
         new_section_page GET    /chapters/:section_id/pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
        edit_section_page GET    /chapters/:section_id/pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
             section_page GET    /chapters/:section_id/pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
                          PUT    /chapters/:section_id/pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
                          DELETE /chapters/:section_id/pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy
                 sections GET    /chapters(.:format)                            sections#index
                          POST   /chapters(.:format)                            sections#create
              new_section GET    /chapters/new(.:format)                        sections#new
             edit_section GET    /chapters/:id/edit(.:format)                   sections#edit
                  section GET    /chapters/:id(.:format)                        sections#show
                          PUT    /chapters/:id(.:format)                        sections#update
                          DELETE /chapters/:id(.:format)                        sections#destroy
```

Comment: How does that fit with the nested routes block?

Comment: The nested relationship remains the same. Declare it as you would normally.

Comment: OK thanks. if I wanted to redirect the old paths to the new ones, can I just use `get '/sections', to: redirect('/chapters')` or I need something more to handle the nested routes?

Comment: Actually, if you look at the routes being output, you'll notice that the named routes actually _remain the same_. Thus, any references you already have to paths named `sections` will _automatically_ be routed to your updated routes. You don't need to declare any other routes to get your existing paths/links rerouted.

Comment: But what about hard-coded URLs, either on my site or elsewhere? I want them to redirect to the new modules paths.

Comment: If you have hard-coded links, you can either 1) update all your links themselves, or 2) create a match route _for each route_ as you've already suggested in your comments.

Comment: Have this answer addressed your original question to satisfaction? If so, please consider accepting it as correct.